# Is open always Zariski open in the context of Algebraic geometry, unless otherwise mentioned?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, affine-varieties, zariski-topology

Going through Smith et al.'s Invitation to Algebraic Geometry I sometimes find myself wondering whenever they use the word *open*, do they mean open in the usual sense on $\mathbb{A}^1$ for example, or Zariski open? Many times, it is clear from the context. But I am unsure about the context of Section 4.3 on Regular functions.

Especially this definition of to be regular on an affine variety $V$:

> Let $U$ be any open set of an affine variety $V$. A complex-valued function $f : U \to \mathbb{C}$ is regular at a point $p \in U$ if there exist functions $g$ and
> $h$ in (the coordinate ring) $\mathbb{C}[V]$ such that $h(p) \neq 0$ and $f$ agrees with the function $g/h$ in some neighborhood of $p$. The function $f$ is regular on $U$ if it is regular at every point of $U$. The set of all regular functions on $U$ is denoted by $O_V(U)$.

Is $U$ allowed to be ordinary open, or always Zariski open? And does $f$ have to agree with $g/h$ in some Zariski neighbourhood, or can it be an ordinary neighbourhood (which are usually allowed to be much smaller). In the second case, if we allow for the standard opens in $\mathbb{A}^n$, then it seems possible from $h(p) \neq 0$ to find an open around $p$ such that $h \neq 0$ on that open but that is also not that clear to me why it has to be the case for Zariski opens.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio So Zariski open, right?

Comment: Then, still, the second question kinda remains unanswered as it is not as clear to me that neighbourhood in that sense refers to either standard open neighbourhood or Zariski open neighbourhood.

Comment: The set of points in affine space in which a polynomial $h$ does not vanish is open in Zariski topology, so it is easy to find such a neighbourhood.

Comment: @danneks That is true! thank you. That solves it I believe. I'll answer my own question then with that input, if you do not mind.

Comment: @Neckverse Herdman: OK.